# How to add a 1 pixel gray border around a UISearchBar TextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uisearchbar

I'm trying to figure out how to add a 1 pixel stroke gray border to my UISearchBar in my app. The Facebook Messenger app accomplishes this quite well. (see pic below).

I know there is a background image property of UISearchBar, but I believe that is not the right thing to use, as it stretches the image out and repeats it across the entire view of the search bar.

I'd greatly appreciate pointers in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code:

```
//First add the following import and macro:
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)

//Then change yourSearchBar border: 
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
{
    for (id object in [[[yourSearchBar subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews])
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;
            textFieldObject.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
            textFieldObject.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    for (id object in [yourSearchBar subviews])
    {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            UITextField *textFieldObject = (UITextField *)object;
            textFieldObject.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
            textFieldObject.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide Swift solution please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3** version

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for s in searchBar.subviews[0].subviews {
        if s is UITextField {
            s.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            s.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        }
    }
}
```

To make it round you can use *textField.layer.cornerRadius* property

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

Easy way to do

```
    @IBOutlet private weak var searchBar:UISearchBar!{
        didSet{
            if let searchTextfield = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField  {
                searchTextfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                searchTextfield.layer.borderWidth = 1
                searchTextfield.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This work fine:

```
UITextField *txtSearchField = [yourSearchBar valueForKey:@"_searchField"];
[txtSearchField setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
txtSearchField.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
txtSearchField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
txtSearchField.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWhatYouWant] CGColor];
```

do not forget `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: The value for key used is a private key.. Grounds for rejection

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
self.poundsTxt.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];
self.poundsTxt.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
```

import Quartz Core Framework Reference into your project and add
import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
to your ViewController.m to work borderColor and borderWidth.

Comment: Doesn't work. That adds the border to the entire view bounds :( Unless I'm doing it wrong. self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:201.0/255.0 green:201.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]CGColor];

Comment: maybe this link can help you [link](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007529-CH3-SW53)

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted [Yaroslav's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42074080/981049) but it's broken as of iOS 13.  Here is what works *today*:

```
    func changeSearchBarAppearance() {
        var searchTextField : UITextField?
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            // brand new searchTextField is available as of iOS 13
            searchTextField = searchBar.searchTextField
        } else {
            // Yaroslav's answer still works in iOS versions less than 13
            // here's a slightly different implementation:
            if let matchingTextField = searchBar.subviews[0].subviews.compactMap ({ $0 as? UITextField }).first {
                searchTextField = matchingTextField
            }
        }

        guard let validTextField = searchTextField else {
            return
        }

        validTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 16
        validTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        validTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grey.cgColor
        validTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        validTextField.placeholder = "insert-some-placeholder-text"
    }
```

Comment: Great solution.  FYI .grey is .gray for me.  But I'm using .lightGray because it seems a little cleaner on a white background.