# Customize UISearchBar in Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, customization, swift4

- I need to delete the background of the search bar.
- The part where text is entered (white color) make it higher.
- put a green border around the white part.
- customize the font.

I need this:

[image: Picture 1]

What I have achieved is this:

[image: Picture 2]

My code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.searchBar.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2352941176, green: 0.7254901961, blue: 0.3921568627, alpha: 1)
    self.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1

    self.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true
    self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 20
}
```

Comment: I think a text field would suit your case better, rather than a search bar. A search bar has a particular look and feel, and you can't change much of it that easily.

Comment: I already managed it, but I can not manipulate the size of the text or the font.

Comment: No matter how close you are to the solution, going for a text field will make your code read nicer and will be easier to modify on the future. I know you are determined to use a search bar but I think it’s not best suited for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code:

```
class JSSearchView : UIView {

    var searchBar : UISearchBar!

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        // the actual search barw
        self.searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: self.frame)

        self.searchBar.clipsToBounds = true

        // the smaller the number in relation to the view, the more subtle
        // the rounding -- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/calayer/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-uiview
        self.searchBar.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        self.addSubview(self.searchBar)

        self.searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.searchBar, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)
        let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.searchBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20)
        let yConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.searchBar, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)

        self.addConstraints([yConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])

        self.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
        self.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        self.searchBar.isTranslucent = true

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21191801/how-to-add-a-1-pixel-gray-border-around-a-uisearchbar-textfield/21192270
        for s in self.searchBar.subviews[0].subviews {
            if s is UITextField {
                s.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                s.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                s.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
            }
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        // the half height green background you wanted...            
        let topRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: (self.frame.height / 2)))
        UIColor.green.set()
        UIRectFill(topRect)
    }
}
```

And to use it, drop a custom view into your xib or storyboard file and simply set the custom class type to the name of the class (`JSSearchView`).